# Wordpress - Redirect based on IP address

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm making a Wordpress function that redirects the user to a different page when they're on a certain IP address. The code however does not function properly and I can't get it to work.

```
function ip_based_login() 
{
    if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '95.81.51.134') 
    {
        wp_redirect("examplewebsite.com/login2"(site_url($wp->request)));
    } 
    else 
    {
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont really need to write a code for that 
The best thing about wordpress is that there are tons of stuff already available 
You can use the following plugin for your requirements 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-redirect/

Answer (score 0):

`site_url` expects a path to attach to the site url(eg: `site_url('hello') => https://example.com/hello`.

`$wp->request` contains the path of the request which means doing `site_url($wp->request)` will return you the url you are on.

here is a working snippet, just replace `$url` with the url you want to redirect to.

```
function ip_based_login() {
    $visitor = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $redirectTo = site_url('login2');

    if (preg_match("/95.81.51.134/",$visitor)) {
        wp_redirect($redirectTo);
    }

    exit;
}
```

keep in mind that placing this snippet in `functions.php` without hooking it to a specific action can cause an infinite redirect loop.